# Hierarchical clustering with pearson's correlation

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram, pearson-correlation

I would like to make a graph in which I compare viral abundance and metabolic readouts, and have already calculated the Pearson's correlation coefficients for each comparison. I would like to hierarchically cluster my data based on the Pearson's correlation coefficients. I attempted to do this by:

```html
##r contains a matrix of correlation coefficients
dissimilarity <- 1-abs(r)
dist = as.dist(dissimilarity)
Warning message:
In as.dist.default(dissimilarity) : non-square matrix
plot(hclust(dist))
Error in hclust(dist) : dissimilarities of improper length
```

However, because the axes are different, it spits out errors. 
You can find the correlation coefficients [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WpfIUjCynVrmI328MgsSxRjo0YHy_nD3S1JuCPn_1Mg/edit?usp=sharing). Is this even possible? Thanks in advance!

*Edit: 
1. My data is in two sheets, both are headed and str below:

Virus:

```html
'data.frame': 6 obs. of  81 variables:
 $ X0305phi8.36.like.viruses                   : num  0.02074 0 0.07831 0 0.00977 ...
 $ Bcep22.like.viruses                         : num  0.12443 1.66016 0.23493 0.11682 0.00977 ...
 $ BcepMu.like.viruses                         : num  0.0104 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FelixO1.like.viruses                        : num  0.0207 0 0.3915 0 0 ...
 $ HAP1.like.viruses                           : num  0.03111 0 0 0.02336 0.00977 ...
 $ Hp1.like.viruses                            : num  0 0.0977 0 0 0 ...
 $ JS98.like.viruses                           : num  0 0 0 0.0234 0 ...
 $ K.like.viruses                              : num  0 0 0 0 0 ...

      X0305phi8.36.like.viruses Bcep22.like.viruses BcepMu.like.viruses
    1               0.020738283         0.124429697          0.01036914
    2               0.000000000         1.660156250          0.00000000
    3               0.078308536         0.234925607          0.00000000
    4               0.000000000         0.116822430          0.00000000
    5               0.009774216         0.009774216          0.00000000
    6               0.000000000         0.010016026          0.00000000
      FelixO1.like.viruses HAP1.like.viruses Hp1.like.viruses JS98.like.viruses
    1           0.02073828       0.031107424       0.00000000        0.00000000
    2           0.00000000       0.000000000       0.09765625        0.00000000
    3           0.39154268       0.000000000       0.00000000        0.00000000
    4           0.00000000       0.023364486       0.00000000        0.02336449
    5           0.00000000       0.009774216       0.00000000        0.00000000
    6           0.00000000       0.040064103       0.00000000        0.00000000
      K.like.viruses P1.like.viruses P100.like.viruses P2.like.viruses PAKP1.like.viruses
    1     0.00000000      0.01036914        0.04147657      0.05184571         0.00000000
    2     0.00000000      0.00000000        0.00000000      0.39062500         0.00000000
    3     0.00000000      0.07830854        0.00000000      1.33124511         0.00000000
    4     0.00000000      0.00000000        0.00000000      0.08177570         0.00000000
    5     0.00000000      0.00000000        0.00000000      0.02932265         0.00000000
    6     0.01001603      0.00000000        0.02003205      0.01001603         0.01001603
      PB1.like.viruses phiCD119.like.viruses phiKZ.like.viruses phiPLPE.like.viruses
    1                0             2.2397346         0.01036914           0.06221485
    2                0            16.7968750         0.00000000           0.09765625
    3                0            12.5293657         0.39154268           0.15661707
    4                0             0.4556075         0.01168224           0.00000000
    5                0             0.1759359         0.01954843           0.00000000
    6                0             0.7712340         0.01001603           0.00000000
       RB49.like rV5.like.viruses Schizot4.like.viruses Secunda5.like.viruses
    1 0.00000000      0.000000000            0.00000000            0.02073828
    2 0.09765625      0.097656250            0.00000000            0.19531250
    3 0.07830854      0.000000000            0.00000000            0.00000000
    4 0.00000000      0.000000000            0.00000000            0.00000000
    5 0.00000000      0.009774216            0.00000000            0.00000000
    6 0.00000000      0.010016026            0.01001603            0.00000000
      SfV.like.viruses SP18.like.viruses SPO1.like.viruses T4.like.viruses
    1                0         0.0000000         0.6325176       1.3583575
    2                0         0.3906250         0.1953125       6.9335938
    3                0         0.4698512         1.4878622       6.1080658
    4                0         0.5490654         0.7827103       0.3037383
    5                0         0.3616460         0.3518718       0.7037435
    6                0         0.2203526         1.3922276       0.2604167
      Twort.like.viruses unclassified..derived.from.Myoviridae.
    1        0.134798839                            0.041476566
    2        0.195312500                            0.000000000
    3        2.114330462                            0.000000000
    4        0.023364486                            0.011682243
    5        0.009774216                            0.009774216
    6        0.020032051                            0.030048077
      Unclassified..derived.from.Spounavirinae. VHML.like.viruses Vi1.like.viruses
    1                                0.02073828        0.02073828                0
    2                                0.00000000        0.00000000                0
    3                                0.15661707        0.00000000                0
    4                                0.00000000        0.00000000                0
    5                                0.04887108        0.00000000                0
    6                                0.03004808        0.00000000                0
      Bcep781.like.viruses Bpp.1.like.viruses Epsilon15.like.viruses F116.like.viruses
    1           0.00000000          1.1198673                      0        0.00000000
    2           0.00000000          3.2226562                      0        0.00000000
    3           2.50587314          4.9334377                      0        0.00000000
    4           0.00000000          0.7593458                      0        0.00000000
    5           0.06841951          0.0000000                      0        0.01954843
    6           0.00000000          1.1418269                      0        0.00000000
      KP34.like.viruses LUZ24.like.viruses N4.like.viruses P22.like.viruses
    1       0.020738283         0.03110742               0       0.01036914
    2       0.097656250         0.00000000               0       0.00000000
    3       0.000000000         0.00000000               0       0.00000000
    4       0.000000000         0.00000000               0       0.01168224
    5       0.009774216         0.01954843               0       0.00000000
    6       0.010016026         0.00000000               0       0.00000000
      P68.like.viruses Phi29.like.viruses phiKMV.like.viruses SP6.like.viruses
    1        0.4562422         0.18664455                   0       0.03110742
    2        0.0000000         0.00000000                   0       0.00000000
    3        0.1566171         1.09631950                   0       0.00000000
    4        0.6892523         0.01168224                   0       0.01168224
    5        0.7232920         0.00000000                   0       0.02932265
    6        0.8613782         0.22035256                   0       0.00000000
      T7.like.viruses unclassified..derived.from.Podoviridae.
    1      0.14516798                              0.01036914
    2      0.00000000                              0.19531250
    3      0.00000000                              0.15661707
    4      0.03504673                              0.02336449
    5      0.08796794                              0.04887108
    6      0.10016026                              0.15024039
      unclassified..derived.from.Autogrphivirinae. unclassified..derived.from.Picovirinae.
    1                                   0.01036914                                       0
    2                                   0.00000000                                       0
    3                                   0.00000000                                       0
    4                                   0.00000000                                       0
    5                                   0.00000000                                       0
    6                                   0.00000000                                       0
      X1706.like.viruses X3a.like.viruses X77.like.viruses X936.like.viruses
    1          1.0161759       0.00000000       0.00000000        0.31107424
    2          9.0820312       0.00000000       0.09765625        0.29296875
    3          9.9451840       0.39154268       0.07830854        0.07830854
    4          1.2149533       0.00000000       0.00000000        0.26869159
    5          0.3323233       0.01954843       0.00000000        0.30300068
    6          0.8012821       0.03004808       0.00000000        0.68108974
      c2.like.viruses Che8.like.viruses CJW1.like.viruses D3.like.viruses
    1      0.05184571        0.42513480                 0      0.01036914
    2      0.00000000        0.09765625                 0      0.00000000
    3      0.15661707        0.39154268                 0      0.00000000
    4      0.01168224        0.01168224                 0      0.00000000
    5      0.04887108        0.03909686                 0      0.00000000
    6      0.06009615        0.00000000                 0      0.00000000
      HK578.like.viruses IEBH.like.viruses Jersey.like.viruses L5.like.viruses
    1                  0         0.7673165          0.00000000     0.010369141
    2                  0         3.2226562          0.09765625     0.292968750
    3                  0         3.9154268          0.00000000     0.391542678
    4                  0         1.1565421          0.00000000     0.268691589
    5                  0         0.8601310          0.00000000     0.009774216
    6                  0         1.0116186          0.00000000     0.000000000
      Lambda.like.viruses Lebron.like.viruses Omega.like.viruses P23.45.like.viruses
    1           0.4769805                   0         0.00000000                   0
    2           0.4882812                   0         0.29296875                   0
    3           2.7407987                   0         0.00000000                   0
    4           0.0817757                   0         0.00000000                   0
    5           0.1075164                   0         0.00000000                   0
    6           0.4306891                   0         0.01001603                   0
      P335.like.viruses PhiC31.like.viruses phiE125.like.viruses phiETA.like.viruses
    1         27.467856                   0           0.21775197            2.250104
    2          4.296875                   0           1.56250000            1.855469
    3          2.505873                   0           1.80109632            1.566171
    4         25.747664                   0           0.18691589            2.207944
    5         30.016616                   0           0.16616167            4.613430
    6         19.741587                   0           0.09014423            3.175080
      phiFL.like.viruses phiLJ1.like.viruses PsiM1.like.viruses Sfi11.like.viruses
    1          15.325591         0.010369141                  0         0.04147657
    2           3.417969         0.292968750                  0         0.00000000
    3           6.186374         0.078308536                  0         0.00000000
    4          17.266355         0.058411215                  0         0.07009346
    5          14.524484         0.009774216                  0         0.05864529
    6          17.387821         0.010016026                  0         0.10016026
      Sfi21.like.viruses SPbeta.like.viruses T5.like.viruses TLS.like.viruses
    1         0.06221485           0.6532559      0.03110742                0
    2         0.39062500           1.1718750      0.00000000                0
    3         0.62646828           2.7407987      0.00000000                0
    4         0.09345794           0.3621495      0.00000000                0
    5         0.04887108           0.2834523      0.00000000                0
    6         0.13020833           0.3205128      0.00000000                0
      TM4.like.viruses TP21.like.viruses unclassified..derived.from.Siphoviridae.
    1       0.00000000         1.8871837                                 41.45583
    2       0.00000000         0.3906250                                 30.37109
    3       0.00000000         0.3132341                                 21.84808
    4       0.00000000         0.9579439                                 46.00467
    5       0.00000000         2.0916821                                 43.41707
    6       0.01001603         1.9631410                                 48.29728
      Wbeta.like.viruses Xp10.like.viruses Yua.like.viruses Cvm10.like.viruses
    1         0.10369141                 0                0                  0
    2         0.00000000                 0                0                  0
    3         0.00000000                 0                0                  0
    4         0.04672897                 0                0                  0
    5         0.04887108                 0                0                  0
    6         0.05008013                 0                0                  0
      unclassified..derived.from.Caudovirales.
    1                               0.54956450
    2                              11.62109375
    3                               9.78856695
    4                               0.04672897
    5                               0.24435539
    6                               0.36057692
```

Metab:

```html
'data.frame': 6 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Day.EE               : num  0.366 0.334 0.348 0.425 0.454 ...
 $ Night.RER            : num  0.941 0.884 0.948 0.771 0.849 ...
 $ Visceral.Fat         : num  0.0283 0.0356 0.0256 0.0726 0.0928 ...
 $ Percent.Weight.Change: num  21.4 20 20.3 40.5 42.2 ...
 $ HOMA.IR              : num  8.43 7.91 4.64 22.96 33.25 ...
 
 
 head(D2)
     Day.EE Night.RER Visceral.Fat Percent.Weight.Change   HOMA.IR
1 0.3659900 0.9409150   0.02830189              21.43435  8.428624
2 0.3338380 0.8838706   0.03564390              20.04065  7.906044
3 0.3477030 0.9478585   0.02556391              20.30075  4.642277
4 0.4249553 0.7709375   0.07257911              40.48837 22.961244
5 0.4544125 0.8494122   0.09284971              42.22649 33.246229
6 0.4864046 0.8814634   0.08163690              45.03449 35.661550
>
```

Here is a head of my coefficients:

```html
                              Day.EE   Night.RER Visceral.Fat Percent.Weight.Change
X0305phi8.36.like.viruses -0.4744741  0.64074328   -0.5746224            -0.5330374
Bcep22.like.viruses       -0.6353393  0.09046829   -0.4410990            -0.5588352
BcepMu.like.viruses       -0.2857413  0.46571242   -0.4591139            -0.4096812
FelixO1.like.viruses      -0.4492620  0.54772835   -0.5335849            -0.4815672
HAP1.like.viruses          0.6324260 -0.14644627    0.3638282             0.5263814
Hp1.like.viruses          -0.5393393  0.03610703   -0.3378353            -0.4659172
                             HOMA.IR
X0305phi8.36.like.viruses -0.5648587
Bcep22.like.viruses       -0.4982786
BcepMu.like.viruses       -0.3714296
FelixO1.like.viruses      -0.5315103
HAP1.like.viruses          0.5154564
Hp1.like.viruses          -0.3901310
```

Comment: Please post a) the result of `str` on your dataset, and `head` so we can see a couple of lines b) the errors c)  `head` of the correlation coefficients here. Please actually post those things here (not a link or an image).

Comment: lmk if that's what you needed!